# IllegalArgumentException when calling Collections.sort with Comparator

Tags: java, android, sorting

i'm making an app that makes an API request and gets back a list of Games, with one of the fields being the release date in seconds Timestamp.
When i make the call for e.g. call of duty the sorting goes well, but if i do so for like zelda it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

I filter out the ones that return a null release date, but I don't know why with some games it just don't work.

Here is the code for the sorting

```
Collections.sort(mGames, new Comparator<Game>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Game o1, Game o2) {
                        if(o1.getDate() != null && o2.getDate() != null)
                            return Integer.valueOf(o2.getDate()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o1.getDate()));
                        return 1;
                    }
                });
```

and the responses (some of them) for spyro search (which works)

```
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 941500800 Name  = Spyro 2: Ripto's Rage!
```

`2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1542067200 Name  = Spyro Reignited Trilogy
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1086220800 Name  = Spyro Orange: The Cortex Conspiracy
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1004313600 Name  = Spyro: Season of Ice
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 972432000 Name  = Spyro: Year of the Dragon
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1067212800 Name  = Spyro: Attack of the Rhynocs
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1191283200 Name  = The Legend of Spyro: The Eternal Night
2020-06-04 01:07:22.723 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1542067200 Name  = Spyro + Crash Remastered Game Bundle
2020-06-04 01:07:22.724 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = null Name  = Spyro Fusion
2020-06-04 01:07:22.724 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = null Name  = Spyro Superpack`

and for e.g. pokemon, just some, (which crashes and caused the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!`

`2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1573776000 Name  = Pokémon Sword & Pokémon Shield Double Pack
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1129766400 Name  = Pokémon Trozei!
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1366761600 Name  = Pokémon Rumble U
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1141603200 Name  = Pokemon Link!
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 913939200 Name  = Pokémon Trading Card Game
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = null Name  = Pokemon-e: Expedition
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1413849600 Name  = Camp Pokémon
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 943142400 Name  = Pokémon Gold
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 924048000 Name  = Pokémon Pinball
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 1075334400 Name  = Pokémon FireRed
2020-06-04 01:08:24.100 26928-26928/it.unimib.disco.gruppoade.gamenow D/SearchActivity: onResponse: Release date = 925430400 Name  = Pokémon Stadium`

as you can see they both have some that contain the date and some null.
But spyro works and pokemon doesn't and I can't understand why.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The sorting algorithm in Java auto-detects violations of the contract of the `Comparator`.

You can read it in the documentation of `Comparator`/`Comparable`.

> 1. The implementor must ensure that **sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y, x))** for all x and y. (This implies that compare(x, y) must throw an exception if and only if compare(y, x) throws an exception.)
> 2. The implementor must also ensure that the relation is transitive: **((compare(x, y)>0) && (compare(y, z)>0)) implies compare(x, z)>0**.
> 3. Finally, the implementor must ensure that **compare(x, y)==0 implies that sgn(compare(x, z))==sgn(compare(y, z)) for all z**.

You have violated the requirements by returning `1` when either of dates are null.

So consider:

```
// a.getDate() == null
// b.getDate() != null

Comparator yourComparator = ...;
yourComparator.compare(a, b); // returns 1 - that means b > a
yourComparator.compare(b, a); // returns 1 - that means a > b
```

Which is impossible and violates the first rule.

Change the comparator so that it adheres to the rules when either of date is null so it's behaving consistently.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still don't understand where and how to change the comparator

Answer (score 1):

To Krzysztof

I tried changing it like so

```
 Collections.sort(mGames, new Comparator<Game>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Game o1, Game o2) {
                        if(o1.getDate() != null && o2.getDate() != null)
                            return Integer.valueOf(o2.getDate()).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o1.getDate()));
                        if(o1.getDate() == null && o2.getDate() == null)
                            return 0;
                        if(o1.getDate() == null)
                            return -1;
                        return 1;
                    }
                });
```

and it works. I'm still open to advices

Comment: Don’t use `Integer`, it creates a [year 2038 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem). I suggest `Long.compare(Long.parseLong(o1.getDate()), Long.parseLong(o2.getDate()))`.